# Sometimes I'm ugly, sometimes I'm art. What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Sometimes I'm ugly, sometimes I'm art,
Sometimes I'm near and dear to your heart,
I have been known to bring about pain,
And yet I deliver relief just the same,
You know where I live, yes you know it best,
For I am not hidden like all of the rest.

What am I?

**Hint #1**

> I come from a family where we each have a twin, 
>  Even when we're well nourished, we always stay thin

Comment: I think you should add your hint directly to the riddle. It helps narrow down the possible answers.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind! This is the first riddle I wrote, so I'm still getting a feel for how to organize it

Comment: You could be anything, Beauty is in the eye of the beholder

Comment: Reading the title, my first guess was "war" - mostly because I'd just finished reading The Art of War.

Comment: @CodeMoose My guess from the title was still just "art"

Comment: This is well written, but needs to be a bit more specific. There are a lot of things that can be made to fit as well as your chosen answer. What could you add that makes the desired answer better than all others? The hint helps, but it could still use more.

Comment: @NonsenseSynapse I gotta say though, you have a gift for rhyme and meter. It flows really well!

Comment: My little brother.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**NEW GUESS**

I think you're a

> fingernail

Sometimes I'm ugly, sometimes I'm art,

> Sometimes people let their nails get out of hand, other times they get them painted.

Sometimes I'm near and dear to your heart,

> People move their hands, bringing their nails close to their heart.

I have been known to bring about pain,

> Nails can scratch.

And yet I deliver relief just the same,

> Nails can scratch (itches).

You know where I live, yes you know it best,

> You know where your fingernails are...

For I am not hidden like all of the rest.

> Fingernails aren't hidden like the rest of your <del>'bones'</del> toenails.

I come from a family where we each have a twin,

> We have two hands, and so we have two of each 'kind' of finger.

Even when we're well nourished, we always stay thin

> Fingernails don't get fat, even when we're well fed. They just elongate.

**PREVIOUS GUESS**

> Poem

Comment: Fingernails aren't bones; they're made of keratin. Still, it looks like this is right. Unfortunately I already upvoted for 'poem' and can't upvote again!

Comment: Nice! You got it!

Comment: Not sure what "I am not hidden like all of the rest" refers to but... nice job.

Comment: That one was a reference to toe nails (hidden because they're often in socks or shoes). Also "You know where I live, yes you know it best" was referring to the expression "I know that like the back of my hand," referring to knowing something extremely well.

Comment: "Sometimes people let their nails get out of hand" - intentional pun?

Comment: I didn't even think about that one! Hahaha

Answer (score 30):

You are a

> Testicle

Sometimes I'm ugly

> Well they are.

sometimes I'm art,

> many famous statues have them still attached

Sometimes I'm near and dear to your heart

> When boys are young, and they haven't dropped yet they're much closer to the heart than normal

I have been known to bring about pain

> indeed

And yet I deliver relief just the same

> heh, yeah they do.

You know where I live, yes you know it best,

> check

For I am not hidden like all of the rest.

> they're out in the open, unlike the rest of your guts.

The additional hint:

> I'm pretty sure they don't grow and shrink due to how well you're nourished

Comment: All I can say is **:-O** (and +1)

Comment: Seriously brilliant!

Comment: Hahah, I love this answer! :D

Answer (score 8):

Am I:

> A Truth?

Sometimes I'm ugly, sometimes I'm art,

> The Truth can be ugly, but when you not telling the truth (lying), it can be an art

Sometimes I'm near and dear to your heart,

> Truth to your heart!

I have been known to bring about pain,

> Knowing the truth can be painful

And yet I deliver relief just the same,

> But also a relief to know it

You know where I live, yes you know it best,

> You know when you're truth to yourself

For I am not hidden like all of the rest.

> A Truth will always 'come out'?

Comment: Not quite. Try checking the added hint!

Answer (score 5):

Fourth try:

> Hmmm I suppose bones would also fit the riddle. A ribcage is near and dear to your heart, they provide relief in that gravity doesn't turn us into piles of goo. And technically they're not entirely hidden since you can see teeth. Also, as far as I know all bones come in "twin" pairs and are technically alive inside of you.

Third try:

> Teeth seems to fit a little better since they always stay thin even when someone is well nourished.

Second try:

> Now I'm thinking its a breast, which can get cancer and cause pain but can also provide relief. They are twins, and are usually in plain sight. And they're near and dear to your heart. And are ugly or art, etc.

The first try was

> a crucifix.

Comment: Not quite! Also, try to use spoiler tags for your answers here: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers

Comment: Not sure why a downvote was necessary, but I added the tag all the same.

Comment: Alright, explanation added.

Comment: Your thought process is in the right place.

Comment: Added a hint. See if that helps!

Comment: Added a new guess

Comment: Closer, but still not what I was thinking of.

Comment: Okay, okay. I think I got it this time. Maybe.

Comment: You're so close!

Comment: Alright, one more try before my head explodes XD

Comment: seems like it would be a rib but I don't understand why it would be ugly or art...

Comment: Oh... and it's *not* hidden

Answer (score 3):

**Updated guess**

This is very silly I realize, but it's a guess.

> Alcohol

Sometimes I'm ugly, sometimes I'm art

> Alcohol can be ugly at times. But people rejoice and celebrate with it.

I have been known to bring about pain

> Alcohol causes brain damage and damage to your body.

And yet I deliver relief just the same

> People drink when they feel bad.

You know where I live, yes you know it best

> It is easy to find alcohol these days at stores.

For I am not hidden like all of the rest

> Some drugs are illegal but alcohol is legal.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I'm not for sure, but I guess this fits your riddle. Is it

> Love?

Comment: Nope. Some of the clues might be less abstract than you think.

Comment: @Keith OK, whoops, I was looking on a more literal note :)

Comment: @Len OK, thanks Len, I have added a different anwer.

Comment: Not the one I was thinking of, but I really like your answer! Fits well with all of the juxtaposition.

Comment: Added a hint. See if that helps!

Answer (score 3):

You are a

> tattoo

Sometimes I'm ugly, sometimes I'm art,

> Tattoos can be ugly, but many people consider them art.

Sometimes I'm near and dear to your heart,

> You can get a tattoo on your chest.

I have been known to bring about pain,

> Getting a tattoo can be painful.

And yet I deliver relief just the same,

> After it's done you may be relieved and enjoy how it looks on you.

You know where I live, yes you know it best,

> I would hope you know where your tattoo is located.

For I am not hidden like all of the rest.

> Most people get tattoos to show them off.  If it's hidden, what's the point?

Comment: Not quite. Try looking at the hint! I can add another hint as well if people are still having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Is it hands?
not sure about the art/ugly
hand on heart
can inflict pain or relief
I know it like the back of my hand
you don't tend to cloth your hands

Answer (score 1):

Skin.

"I come from a family where we each have a twin"
For every piece of skin on your body there is a symmetrical counterpart.

"Even when we're well nourished, we always stay thin"
Skin is thin regardless how fat you are

Answer (score 0):

> Nipple(s)

.

> Sometimes I'm ugly, sometimes I'm art,

Depends on person to person

> Sometimes I'm near and dear to your heart,

Physical proximity to heart.

> I have been known to bring about pain,
>
> And yet I deliver relief just the same,

This one I am unsure about, perhaps pleasure?

> You know where I live, yes you know it best,
>
> For I am not hidden like all of the rest.